# How do I express "create new if [this data] does not already exist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'm programming and want to create a variable only if it does not already exist.

Is there a way to express this with a single word?

For example, if the variable already exists, I have the options

- *overwrite* to overwrite the current value with a new value
- *append* to append new data to existing data

I'm searching for the word to express *if the data already exists, leave it alone, otherwise take the given data*.

Comment: In database terms this is called an 'insert or update'

Comment: This is a common scenario, but to my knowledge there is no single term that covers most of the possible situations.  The closest, perhaps, is "singleton", but it only applies to a narrow range of problems (and, as a programming concept, it stinks).

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you want to **ensure existence** of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

**Merge** is what you are looking for, at least in the SQL lexicon.

It is also called an **Upsert**, which indicates data can be updated where it exists and inserted where it does not.

This does not necessarily mean that existing data *will* be updated; existing data can be left as is.

[Boring technical link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: @eckes My initial answer was incomplete.  Edited.